# Is there a way to use IS_VALID_JSON with SUPER datatype in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

**IS_VALID_JSON()** function in redshift returns an error if I used it with a column has **SUPER** datatype,
Is there a way to use it or another function to validate the JSON columns for SUPER?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the super field to a string?

```
select is_valid_json(json_field::varchar(max)), *
from yourschema.yourtable;
```

Comment: What if the characters size more than the text max size?

Comment: Updated answer to use varchar which caps out at 65,000 characters instead of text which is 256 I think. If you're going longer than that, you'll have to explore a more complex option.

Comment: yes I need it to the super max size, thanks anyway